# Ошибка юникод на ровном месте

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, unicode

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\untitled3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs')
```

Если повернуть слеш в другую сторону ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а так пробовали:

```
d = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\\Users\\lolo\\PycharmProjects\\untitled3\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\phantomjs')
```

?

в том виде, что у вас был ругается так:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

т.е. он видит `\U` которую вос принимает как некоторую юникод-последовательность, которой нет

Comment: Появляется ошибка raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable may have wrong permissions.

Comment: но это уже из другой области - для этого уже приводите код полностью

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\\Users\\lolo\\PycharmProjects\\untitled3\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\phantomjs') И больше ничего

Comment: проверьте путь, все в нем правильно, `phantomjs` или `phantom.js`?

Comment: После указания в конце .js появляется это: raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs.js' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446084/webdriverexception-message-phantomjs-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions